# Stream SDK Push Notification Paylaod

Tags: getstream-io

I am currently implementing Stream chat SDK in my react native app. When implementing push notifications, I was able to test and receive messages using `stream chat:push:test --user_id` command and actually sending messages in the app, but the payload I receive from Stream is always just

> Here is the generic rendered notification payload that will be sent to
> your devices: {
> "sender": "stream.chat",
> "type": "message.new",
> "version": "v2",
> "message_id": "88280bc0-23d6-43b9-b9e3-062b3a1a3dca",
> "id": "88280bc0-23d6-43b9-b9e3-062b3a1a3dca",
> "channel_type": "shellterChat",
> "channel_id": "courseChatENES462JamesGreen202201",
> "cid": "shellterChat:courseChatENES462JamesGreen202201" }

Currently, I am running client.getMessage() with the messageId from the payload to fetch the actual message, and display using Firebase Notifee, but this is problematic because I can't do the fetching when the app is at quit state (at index.js in my react native app). Am I missing something? Should the stream push payload include the actual message (including title, body, etc for push)? The document just says SDK will automatically handle it, which doesn't really make sense to me. Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score -1):

React Native Firebase library provides a nice to handle background and quit state of the application as mentioned here - https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage#background-application-state

Comment: Yes. So I was able to receive the payloads, but my question is that my payload doesn't include any "message: " (like title and body text). It only has the data section which includes channelId, messageId, etc. I found a workaround to run client.getMessage(), but I was just wondering if it is correct that the push payload doesn't actually include the message itself?

Comment: Yes, calling client.getMessage() is the correct way to fetch message info. Currently we are in process of updating Push v2 related docs for React Native SDK.

`const client = StreamChat.getInstance('api_key');
client._setToken({ id: 'user_id' }, 'token');
client.getMessage('messageId');`

This way you can avoid establishing websocket connection in background or quit state or application.

Comment: @VishalNarkhede, it is unclear to me where one should get the user_id or token. Is this something you would get from local storage after you have made connectUser previously?